# Java: convert a time from today to a timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp

I am using Java 6, and I have a time from the current date as a string, like this: `14:21:16`, and I need to convert this to a [`Timestamp` object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) to store in a database.

However there seems to be no good way to get a Timestamp from this. [`Timestamp.valueOf(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) is quite close, but requires a date. Is there a good way to make a Timestamp object from such a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
final String str = "14:21:16";
final Timestamp timestamp =
    Timestamp.valueOf(
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd ")
        .format(new Date()) // get the current date as String
        .concat(str)        // and append the time
    );
System.out.println(timestamp);
```

Output:

> 2011-03-02 14:21:16.0

Comment: +1 on the basis that it works, and it seems to be easy to come up with answers that don't for reasons we don't understand!

Comment: @Tom yeah, the Java date API is awful, but I believe a working answer without external libraries is a must (even though I like Jon Skeet's answer better)

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I'd use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) to parse the time to a `LocalTime`, and add that to today's `LocalDate` to get a `LocalDateTime`, then convert that into an `Instant` using whatever time zone you're interested in. (Or use `LocalTime.toDateTimeToday(DateTimeZone)`.)

Then just create a time stamp using the `Timestamp(long)` constructor.

There are plenty of other approaches (e.g. using `SimpleDateFormat` instead of parsing with Joda Time, if you really want...) but ultimately you're likely to want the `Timestamp(long)` constructor in the end. (The benefit of using Joda Time here is that it's obvious what's being represented at each stage - you're not trying to treat a "time only" as a "date and time" or vice versa.)

Answer (score 4):

Best I can come up with using standard API is not that pretty:

```
    // Get today's date and time.
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(new Date()); 

    // Get the required time of day, copy year, month, day.
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.setTime(java.sql.Time.valueOf("14:21:16"));
    c2.set(Calendar.YEAR, c1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    c2.set(Calendar.MONTH, c1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    c2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    // Construct required java.sql.Timestamp object.
    Timestamp time = new Timestamp(c2.getTimeInMillis());

    Let's see what we've done.
    System.out.println(time);
```

Note that java.sql.Time.valueOf accepts a string of the form "HH:MM:SS" as you require. Other formats would require use of SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was indeed interested in a solution using just the standard API.

Comment: Totally valid answer, that it's not nice is not your fault :-) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Use org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils:

```
Date today = DateUtils.truncate(new Date(), Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);    
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date time = df.parse("14:21:16");
Timestamp time = new Timestamp(today.getTime() + time.getTime());
```

Comment: +1 for a neater way of getting the time value for the beginning of today, though it does require org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils

Comment: Well, you could also do `long millisToday = new Date().getTime()/86400000; //86400000 the number of milliseconds a per day`

Comment: Btw, the apache commons-lang library provides so many usefull utilities that you'll make your life much easier when using it.

Comment: Does this method actually produce the right answer? (original one) I get an hour out if I try it, and I'm currently in GMT. Can't see why at the moment though

Comment: Strangely the epoch for me (System.out.println(new Date(0))) returns 1 am on 1 Jan 1970 hence the hour out. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, we experienced that as well. Might be a summer/winter time problem.

Comment: Can you post some information on the timezone you're using for that?

Comment: I'm in GMT and it's winter, so Java reports that the current timezone offset is 0. Printing out the value of new Date(0) says 1 am on the 1st Jan 1970 and explicitly GMT. Must say I'm a bit confused by that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a given day (say, unix epoch?) to serve as the day. When you use it, only use the time parameters that you care about, ignoring the day.

Another option would be java.sql.Time

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Time.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "14:21:16";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); 
Date date = formatter.parse(str); 
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

Comment: check what `System.out.println(timestamp)` shows and you will see that's not today's date.